# RedisTemplate expire doesn't work

Tags: java, unit-testing, session, redis

I'm trying to test expire method in RedisTemplate. For example, I store session in redis, and than try to retrieve session and check that values are the same. For expire session I use expire() method of redisTemplate and for getting expired session I use getExpire() method. But it doesn't work. How can I test value, that stored in redis?

```
//without import and fields
public class Cache() {     

    private StringRedisTemplate redisTemplate;

    public boolean expireSession(String session, int duration) {
      return redisTemplate.expire(session, duration, TimeUnit.MINUTES);    
    } 
}

//Test class without imports and fields 
public class TestCache() {  

    private Cache cache = new Cache(); 
    @Test
    public void testExpireSession() {
        Integer duration = 16;
        String session = "SESSION_123";
        cache.expireSession(session, duration);
        assertEquals(redisTemplate.getExpire(session, TimeUnit.MINUTES), Long.valueOf(duration));    
    }    
}
```

but test fails with AssertionError:

> Expected :16 Actual   :0

**UPDATE:**
I thought, that getExpire() method doesn't work, but in fact expire() method doesn't work. It returns false. redisTemplate is a spring Bean that autowired to test  class. There are many other test methods in TestCache class that work correctly.

Comment: Does the key exist, you want to expire? Your code does not contain a part in which a key is created. `expire` returns true, if the expire could be applied. See http://redis.io/commands/pexpire for more details.

Comment: **session**, which I send as a parameter to `redisTemplate.expire()` is a key
`String session = "SESSION_123";`

Comment: I meant, whether the key "SESSION_123" existed at the time of the test on your redis instance.

Comment: It must exist. In my code I expire session with that key. I start redis server before class and stop it after class.

Comment: I don't know why, but redisTemplate return **false** from `expire()` method

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I set up following code to perform a test on `getExpire()` (jedis 2.5.2, spring-data-redis 1.4.2.RELEASE):

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = DemoApplication.class)
public class DemoApplicationTests {

    @Autowired
    private RedisTemplate<String, String> template;

    @Test
    public void contextLoads() {

        template.getConnectionFactory().getConnection().flushAll();

        assertFalse(template.hasKey("key"));
        assertFalse(template.expire("key", 10, TimeUnit.MINUTES));
        assertEquals(0, template.getExpire("key", TimeUnit.MINUTES).longValue());

        template.opsForHash().put("key", "hashkey", "hashvalue");

        assertTrue(template.hasKey("key"));
        assertTrue(template.expire("key", 10, TimeUnit.MINUTES));
        assertTrue(template.getExpire("key", TimeUnit.MINUTES) > 8);
    }

}
```

Depending on your Redis configuration, all Redis data is gone if you restart your Redis instance.

You should also add an assertion to `expireSession` (`assertTrue(cache.expireSession(session, duration));`) to make sure, the expiry worked.

Comment: Why is it required to call flushAll ? I have some code that is clearing the Redis cache each time Tomcat restarts. I found there is a flushAll in the code that returns the RedisTemplate

Comment: That's just for the test case to create a clean state.