# How to use Redis as a session for authentication in spring Boot application

Tags: redis

How can I use Redis for handling a session for authentication in a Spring Boot application?

I tried with using `expire()` of the `RedisTemplate` class:

```
String redisKeyExpiryTime=environment.getProperty("app.redisKeyExpiryTime");
long redisKeyExpiry=Long.parseLong(redisKeyExpiryTime);
redisTemplate.expire(tokenId,1,TimeUnit.MINUTES);
hashOperations.put(userId,tokenId,token);
```

But it is not expiring that key. I am getting value against that tokenId Key even after expiration time over.

Comment: It is `expire()`, not `expiry()`. See also [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30432479/redistemplate-expire-doesnt-work)

Comment: Yes, I had use that expire() . But it's not working. redisTemplate.expire(tokenId,redisKeyExpiry,TimeUnit.MINUTES);         hashOperations.put(userId,tokenId,token);

Comment: OK, I added that info in your question. Could you also edit it further and describe what you mean with "it is not working"? Mention any error message or unexpected behaviour...

Comment: Actually, I am getting that token stored against tokenId even after setting expire time of 2min.

Comment: Could you edit your question and add that information?